# IntelliJ and bootstrap tags conflicts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, twitter-bootstrap-3, schema

My IntelliJ reports wrong attributes on certain tags. For example

```
<div class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" style="margin-left:10px" 
     type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupSendReportError">
```

It reports that attributes type, data-toggle and data-target are not valid attributes. Does anyone know if I need to add some schema for the bootstrap or something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-* attributes are new in HTML5. So mark your html to be HTML5.

Comment: I have done so. The question here is more why does the intellij thinks that those attributes are not correct

Comment: I have tried many options for reproducing this, but only way I get Idea to complain about data-* attributes has been so far to mark html files to HTML 4 or less. I'm using Idea 12.*

Comment: The issues only appears if you use tapestry plugin. It would appear that this is the bug in intellij where they dont force html5 for .tml files